# Functional programming approach to avoid traditional loops

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style

I'm currently learning from the wonderful post:

[Where can I find examples of good Mathematica programming practice?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18/where-can-i-find-examples-of-good-mathematica-programming-practice/259#259)

And i'm correcting my habits using Nest/Map/Thread instead of loops. The problem that i'm having is that i cannot find a clear/elegant expression using functional programming aproaches to do the following:

Imagine that you have a nxn matrix. I want to create a function that for each non-border entry of the matrix ( $i,j \neq 1,n$ ) the result will be the sum of all adjacent entries. For example:

$ f(A_{i,j} )= A_{i-1,j-1}+A_{i,j-1}+A_{i+1,j-1}+A_{i-1,j}+A_{i+1,j}+A_{i-1,j+1}+A_{i,j+1}+A_{i+1,j+1} $.

I'm sure that there will be thousands of elegant ways to do this. I'm really waiting to see your nice approach.

Comment: Hi, take a look at `ListConvolve`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`ListConvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListConvolve.html) or [`ListCorrelate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListCorrelate.html), like this:

```
ListConvolve[
{{1, 1, 1},
 {1, 0, 1},
 {1, 1, 1}}, mat]
```

Comment: And in the case that the function is not Plus? For example, times?

Comment: @PabloGalindoSalgado Did you check the documentation links I posted?  The answer is right there.

Comment: Oh, you are right. So so sorry. Thank you so much!